# Custom Post Type, Custom Taxonomy Template: How to get current taxonomy name?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

Ok so i have a custom post type called 'profile' with a custom taxonomy called 'company'. The site has many profiles and companies defined, with profiles being associated with companies as necessary.

I have created a taxonomy-company.php template and have the correct profiles being displayed, but i don't know how to get the name of the company being displayed so that i can put it at the top of the template.

Is there a quick way, perhaps a variable or function call that gets me that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$wp_query->get_queried_object()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/query.php#L2710) will give you the taxonomy term you're currently displaying. It works in many other situations too, like categories, authors, ...

Comment: what property would i use to display the term name?

Comment: nevermind i got it.